# Possessiv-s bei längeren Namen

Tags: possessive, apostrophe

Wie lautet die korrekte Rechtschreibung in folgendem Satz:

> Robin Hood's Aufmerksamkeit galt Bruder Tack's Unterweisung.

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es sich um Deppenapostrophe handelt. Aber die Schreibweise

> Robin Hoods Aufmerksamkeit galt Bruder Tacks Unterweisung.

verursacht mir ebenfalls Schmerzen. Denn das angehängte -s bezieht sich ja auf die komplette Namen, welche aus mehreren Teilen bestehen, was diese Schreibweise unter den Teppich kehrt.

Comment: Und möchtest Du deshalb jetzt Klammern setzen, oder welche Lösung schwebt Dir vor?

Comment: Wäre der Sprachlogik angemessen, aber was z.B. die Dudengrammatik sagt, ob sie sich überhaupt dazu äußert, oder was andere Grammatiker dazu meinen, würde mir reichen als Antwort.

Comment: @shuhalo: Mit Grammatik hat das nichts zu tun.

Answer (score 14):

Laut Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* wird nur der letzte Name dekliniert:

> Anna Marias Erfolge
>   Klaus Peters Geburtstag
>   Gotthold Ephraim Lessings Werke
>   die Werke Rainer Maria Rilkes
>   in der Dichtung Ricarda Huchs

Einen Sonderfall stellen gezählte Vornamen dar, die auch flektiert werden müssen

> die Feldzüge Gustavs II. Adolfs

Wenn eine Präposition zu dem Familiennamen gehört, wird heute gewöhnlich der Familienname flektiert:

> ein Gedicht Joseph von Eichendorffs
>   Adolph von Menzels Zeichnungen
>   Heinrich von Kleists Werke
>   die Bilder Anton van Dycks
>   der Sieg Hein ten Hoffs

Wenn jedoch der der Familienname noch deutlich als Ortsname zu erkennen ist, wird der Vorname flektiert:

> die Lieder Walthers von der Vogelweide
>   der »Parzival« Wolframs von Eschenbach
>   die Geschichte Gottfriedens von Berlichingen
>   die Erfindungen Leonardos da Vinci
>   die Predigten Abrahams a San[c]ta Clara
>   die Regierung Katharinas I. von Russland

Wenn Zweifel bestehen, werden meistens die Ortsnamen wie andere Familiennamen flektiert:

> die Erfindungen Leonardo da Vincis

Wenn der Name als Genitivattribut unmittelbar vor dem dazugehörenden Nominalausdruck steht, wird immer häufiger der Ortsname wie ein Familienname flektiert:

> Wolfram von Eschenbachs »Parzival« (auch noch: Wolframs von Eschenbach Gedichte, aber nur: die Gedichte Wolframs von Eschenbach)
>   Roswitha von Gandersheims Dichtung (auch noch: Roswithas von Gandersheim Dichtung, aber nur: die Dichtung Roswithas von Gandersheim)

---

Zum Apostroph wird in Duden – *Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* erklärt, dass in der Regel kein Apostroph vor dem Genitiv-s von Namen steht – auch nicht, wenn sie abgekürzt werden:

> <strike>Ingeborg Bachmann’s Lyrik</strike>
>   Ingeborg Bachmanns Lyrik
>   I. B.s Lyrik
>   Brechts Dramen
>   Bismarcks Politik
>   Hamburgs Hafen
>   Shelleys Briefe
>   Angela Merkels Europapolitik

Gelegentlich wird jedoch ein Apostroph gesetzt, um die Grundform eines Namens zu verdeutlichen:

> Andrea’s Boutique (zur Unterscheidung vom männlichen Vornamen Andreas)
>   Carlo’s Taverne

Regelgemäß steht der Apostroph zur Kennzeichnung des Genitivs von Namen, die auf -s, -ss, -ß, -tz, -z, -x, -ce enden und keinen Artikel o. Ä. bei sich haben:

> Hans Sachs’ Gedichte
>   Le Mans’ Umgebung
>   Grass’ Blechtrommel
>   Voß’ Übersetzungen
>   Leibniz’ Philosophie
>   Bregenz’ Lage
>   Ringelnatz’ Gedichte
>   Giraudoux’ Werke
>   Bordeaux’ Hafenanlagen
>   das Leben Johannes’ des Täufers
>   Anatole France’ Werke
>   Mendès-France’ Politik

Diese Schreibweise entspricht § 96 (1) des Regelwerks zur deutschen Rechtschreibung. Darüber hinaus steht der Apostroph heute im Allgemeinen auch zur Kennzeichnung des Genitivs von Namen, die zwar anders geschrieben werden, aber ebenfalls auf einen Zischlaut enden:

> Andrić’ Romane
>   Cyrankiewicz’ Staatsbesuch

Answer (score 3):

Der einzige Punkt, an dem die Rechtschreibregeln hierauf eingehen, ist § 97:

> Man kann den Apostroph setzen, wenn Wörter gesprochener Sprache mit Auslassungen bei schriftlicher Wiedergabe undurchsichtig sind.
>
> […]
>
> E: Von dem Apostroph als Auslassungszeichen zu unterscheiden ist der gelegentliche Gebrauch dieses Zeichens zur Verdeutlichung der Grundform eines
> Personennamens vor der Genitivendung *-s* oder vor dem Adjektivsuffix *-sch:
> Carlo’s Taverne, Einstein’sche Relativitätstheorie*

Das kann man nun vielfältig auslegen:

- Die Ergänzung *(E)* schließt den Genetiv-Apostroph aus der Gruppe derjenigen Fälle aus, die unter den Hauptparagraphen fallen (es handelt sich ja explizit nicht um Auslassungen), und verbietet ihn somit ganz (da es keine anderen Regeln gibt, die ihn erlauben). Hiergegen spricht, dass die Beispiele nicht als falsch gekennzeichnet sind und Konstruktionen wie die *Einstein’sche Relativitätstheorie* mehrfach an anderer Stelle als Beispiele auftauchen (für den Genetiv-Apostroph gilt dies jedoch nicht.
- Die Ergänzung erlaubt den Genitiv-Apostroph nur in den seltenen Fällen in denen der normale Genitiv (also Name + *s)* ebenfalls ein Wort oder geläufiger Name ist – z. B. könnte der Genitiv von *Carlo* mit dem Nominativ von *Carlos* verwechselt werden. Damit wären Genitiv-Apostrophe in Deinen Beispielen unzulässig.
- Die Ergänzung erlaubt den Genitiv-Apostroph praktisch immer, da man immer auf die Idee kommen könnte, dass die Grundform eines Eigennamens einer Verdeutlichung bedarf.

In jedem Fall gibt es keine Ausnahmeregelung für mehrteilige Namen. Generell herrscht in der deutschen Rechtschreibung nicht das Paradigma, dass Eigennamen eine gewisse Unberührbarkeit genießen wie zum Beispiel im Englischen, wo *Monte Carlo simulation* nur so geschrieben wird, weil *Monte Carlo* ein Eigenname ist (sonst wäre es *Monte-Carlo simulation;* deutsch: *Monte-Carlo-Simulation).*