# Genitiv-S bei Krankheitsbezeichnungen

Tags: grammatical-case, genitive

Ich habe kürzlich die Phrase gehört

> wegen meines Rheumas

und mich dabei gefragt, ob ein Anhängen des Genitiv-S' in diesem Fall korrekt ist. Ich bin mir bei dem aus dem Griechischen kommenden Fremdwort einfach nicht sicher, ob man es in einer solchen Art verändern kann.

Aus [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=des%20Rheuma%2Cdes%20Rheumas&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdes%20Rheuma%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdes%20Rheumas%3B%2Cc0) habe ich keine relevanten Informationen entnehmen können.

Dann ist mir aber auch aufgefallen, dass *Rheuma* ja nur eine Abkürzung von *Rheumatismus* ist und den kann ich mit *Rheumatismus'* schon in den Genitiv setzen.

Ein weiteres Beispiel oder eine weitere Unklarheit bietet *Parkinson*. Kann man *wegen des Parkinsons* sagen? Natürlich sind *wegen der Parkinson-Krankheit* oder *wegen des Parkinson-Syndroms* zulässig.

Comment: Glaubst Du der Genitiv wird bei Krankheiten anders gehandhabt als in anderen Fällen (Maschinenbau, Mode, Sport, Religion)? Oder geht es um Wörter griechischer Herkunft?

Comment: Übrigens ist es weder richtig, daß _Rheuma_ eine Abkürzung von _Rheumatismus_ ist, noch, daß man _des Rheumatismus_ oder _des Genitiv-s_ mit Apostroph schreibt.

Comment: @chirlu Bezüglich der Abkürzung beziehe ich mich auf die Herkunft laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Rheuma) und  beim Apostroph auf den vorletzten Punkt [dieser Antwort](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/20709/19627)

Comment: @jera Rheuma oder Rheumatismus? Erkrankungen des rheumatischen Formenkreises! ;) Quelle: http://flexikon.doccheck.com/de/Rheuma

Comment: Die Antwort, auf die du dich beziehst, bezieht sich wiederum auf Eigennamen, nicht auf gewöhnliche Wörter. Falls es also einen Herrn Rheumatismus gibt, dann auch Herrn Rheumatismus’ Schuhe; aber eben nur dann. Und _tò rheũma_ ist ein griechisches Wort, eine Abstraktbildung (auf *-ma(t)*, wie Komma, Thema, Zeugma, Syntagma, Lemma und viele andere) zu einem Verb, das ‘fließen’ bedeutet.

Comment: Der Duden ist da recht eindeutig, was den Genitiv des Rheumas angeht http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Rheuma

Comment: +1 für den *Gebrauch* das Genitivs ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Die Formulierung *wegen meines Rheumas* ist nur insofern ungewöhnlich, als man in den meisten Fällen eher *wegen meinem Rheuma* hören würde. Da, wo der Genitiv noch lebt, wird er natürlich auch bei griechischen Fremdwörtern verwendet:

> Seine Behandlung dieses heiklen *Themas* war nicht gerade feinfühlig.
>   Die Geschichte der *Philosophie* erstreckt sich über mehrere Jahrtausende.
>   Damit endete die Herrschaft des *Tyrannen*.
>   Die Vortragsweise dieser *Koryphäe* langweilte sogar ausgesprochene Freunde des *Monologs*.

Dasselbe gilt für Krankheitsbezeichnungen, griechisch oder nicht:

> Die Behandlung des *Diabetes* machte erst mit der Entdeckung des Insulins Fortschritte.
>   Die Erreger der *Tuberkulose* und der *Lepra* sind Mykobakterien.
>   Die Dauer eines typischen *Schnupfens* beträgt etwa eine Woche.

Comment: Danke auch für die Erklärung betreffend der Schuhe des Herrn Rheumatismus.

Answer (score 7):

Eine eindeutige Regelung des Genitivs bei Fremdwörtern gibt es nicht. Die Entscheidung, ob ein Genitiv-s angehängt wird oder nicht, hängt vom Grad der Eindeutschung des Wortes ab: Je gebräuchlicher es im Deutschen geworden ist, desto eher wird das Genitiv-s angehängt.

Sprich: Wenn der Begriff schon Eingang in die Alltagssprache gefunden hat, so wie "Rheuma" und "Parkinson", sollte der Begriff wie ein deutsches Wort dekliniert werden.

Comment: Die Mediziner selbst drücken sich noch darum ;) Die sagen *...wegen rheumatischer Erkrankungen...* (was schon fast "Umgangssprache" ist) oder *...wegen Krankheiten des rheumatischen Formenkreises...*

Comment: Du meinst, dass "Rheuma" Umgangssprache ist? Dann liegst du richtig: http://dgrh.de/wasistrheuma.html.